# Group theory: Subgroup over finite fields

Tags: group-theory

Would I be right in saying that the subgroups of $G=\mathbb{Z}_5$ are the cyclic groups $\langle 1 \rangle = G,\langle 2 \rangle,\langle 3 \rangle <4>$?

Comment: Yes, but your list is redundant.

Comment: *No*. $4 \not\in \mathbb{Z}_4$ so $\langle 4 \rangle $ doesn't make sense to be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Comment: @FireGarden alternatively, $0=4 \in \mathbb Z_4$. The various notations for "equivalence class of", such as $\overline 0 = \overline 4$ or $[0]_4 = [4]_4$, are suppressed here.

Comment: Sorry I put 4 by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

$|G|=5$, so by Lagrange's Theorem, for any subgroup $H$ of $G$, $|H|$ must divide $|G|$. So either $|H|=1$, whence $H=\{1\}$ or $|H|=5$, whence $H=G$. So the only subgroups of $G$ are $\{1\}$ and $G$ itself. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

This answer refers to a previous version of the question.

---

Yes, with the caveat that

$$\langle 3 \rangle = \{3, 3 + 3, 3 + 3 + 3, 3 + 3 + 3 + 3\} = \{3, 2, 1, 0\} = G$$

Comment: And many would prefer writing $\langle 0\rangle$ to $\langle 4\rangle$.

Comment: I included this generator.

Comment: @Faraad Yes, the point is that you've double counted.

Comment: I'm sorry I mean to ask about$ Z_5$. Is this edit true.

Comment: @Faraad All of the subgroups you've listed are the same; they're each equal to $G$ itself. You're missing one.